# swagger-test says invalid URI on valid swagger-spec

Tags: swagger

I noticed that swagger-test needs my "host" element in the swagger-spec to be like this:

```
http://api.myservice.io
```

Rather than what the swagger spec requires, i.e.:

```
api.myservice.io
```

This means that swagger-test would read my final URI as invalid if I use the swagger-spec notation. While if I use the swagger-test notation, swagger-core will end up reading something like http//:http//:api.cloudboost.io, still ending up invalid.

Is this intentional or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The Swagger spec is correct, you don't put the scheme (http, https, etc) into the host attribute.

You should report this bug into the swagger-test project that you're referring to.